# paramconverter not converting parameters

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, routes, symfony4

I have a problem with symfony 4. i'm migrating an existing app from symfony 3.3 to symfony 4 and I get an error I can't correct.

here is my controller :
*BaseController is the controller responding to sm_admin routes*

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(ParamBagService $parambag, CacheService $cache) {
        parent::__construct($parambag, $cache);
        $this->routePrefix = 'sm_adminarea_';
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/", name="adminarea_index")
     * @Template("@SMAdmin/Home/index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction(Area $area = null)
    {
        $this->area = $area;
        return parent::indexAction();
    }
}
```

here is my routes.yaml

```
sm_admin:
    resource: "@SMAdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

sm_admin_area:
    resource: "@SMAdminAreaBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /Area/{area}
```

When I go to the `sm_admin` route, everything is fine. when I go to `/area/the_id_of_area` I get the following error : `argument 1 passed to indexAction must be of type Area or null, string provided` This lets me think that the area parameter is not converted and the document is not retreived from the database.

I tried adding this paramConverter annotation : `@ParamConverter("area", options={"mapping"={"area"="id"}})` but I get the same error...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I found the solution here https://matthiasnoback.nl/2012/10/symfony2-mongodb-odm-adding-the-missing-paramconverter/

The default paramconverter was using doctrine ORM and I use doctrine ODM so i just had to add ths in the servide.yaml :

```
param_converter:
    class: 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter'
    arguments: ['@doctrine_mongodb']
    tags:
        - { name: 'request.param_converter', converter: 'doctrine.odm' }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using

```
@ParamConverter("area", class="YourBundle:Area")
```

as seen http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#usage